# Create home screen quick actions that do not open app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

I have home screen quick actions for my iOS 9 app, but I don't need it to open the app. It actually schedule reminders and that's it. Is there a way to make the home screen quick action not to open the app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick actions are designed to be used to quickly navigate to a section of your app, eg on the camera app there is selfie mode, box mode, panorama mode, timelapse mode etc. These are all sections of the app. To the best of my knowledge you cant have a quick action that just runs code without opening the app. Otherwise how will the user know that the code has worked and it has been executed?

This functionality would be cool but i believe it is impossible as of current. The closest you can get is make it so it opens the app to a ViewController that just says "Reminder Scheduled".